# CKModifyRecordsOperation not working for complete batch of records

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

As I understand it, the `CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave:, recordsToDelete:)` method should make it possible to modify multiple records and delete multiple records all at the same time.

In my code, `recordsToSave` is an array with 2 `CKRecords`. I have no records to delete, so I set `recordsToDelete` to `nil`. Perplexingly enough, it appears that `recordsToSave[0]` gets saved to the cloud properly while `recordsToSave[1]` does not.

To give some more context before I paste my code:

In my app, there's a "Join" button associated with every post on a feed. When the user taps the "Join" button, 2 cloud transactions occur: 1) the post's reference gets added to `joinedList` of type `[CKReference]`, and 2) the post's record should increment its `NUM_PEOPLE` property. Based on the CloudKit dashboard, cloud transaction #1 is occurring, but not #2.

Here is my code, with irrelevant parts omitted:

```
@IBAction func joinOrLeaveIsClicked(_ sender: Any) {

self.container.fetchUserRecordID() { userRecordID, outerError in
    if outerError == nil {
        self.db.fetch(withRecordID: userRecordID!) { userRecord, innerError in
            if innerError == nil {

                var joinedList: [CKReference]

                if userRecord!.object(forKey: JOINED_LIST) == nil {
                    joinedList = [CKReference]() // init an empty list
                }
                else {
                    joinedList = userRecord!.object(forKey: JOINED_LIST) as! [CKReference]
                }

                let ref = CKReference(recordID: self.post.recordID, action: .none)

                // ... omitted some of the if-else if-else ladder

                // add to list if you haven't joined already
                else if !joinedList.contains(ref) {

                    // modifying user record
                    joinedList.append(ref) // add to list
                    userRecord?[JOINED_LIST] = joinedList as CKRecordValue // associate list with user record

                    // modifying post
                    let oldCount = self.post.object(forKey: NUM_PEOPLE) as! Int
                    self.post[NUM_PEOPLE] = (oldCount + 1) as CKRecordValue

                    let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [userRecord!, self.post], recordIDsToDelete: nil)

                    self.db.add(operation)

                }

                    // omitted more of the if-else if-else ladder

            else {
                if let error = innerError as? CKError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        if let error = outerError as? CKError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

}

EDIT

Here's the code I added per the request of the first commenter

```
operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordsIDs, error in
                            if error == nil {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                    self.num.text = String(oldCount + 1) // UI update
                                })
                            }
                            else {
                                print(error!)
                            }
                        }
```

ANOTHER EDIT

```
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [userRecord!, self.post], recordIDsToDelete: nil)

                        operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { record, error in
                            if error != nil {
                                let castedError = error as! NSError
                                print(castedError)
                            }
                        }
                        operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordsIDs, error in
                            if error == nil {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                    self.num.text = String(oldCount + 1) // UI update
                                })
                            }
                            else {
                                print(error!)
                            }
                        }

                        self.db.add(operation)
```

Comment: Have you implemented the `perRecordCompletionBlock` and/or the `modifyRecordsCompletionBlock` to check for errors?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I added some code, which I added to my post above at the bottom. The UI update is not occurring, so there must be an error. My `print(error!)` does not work, however. I am having trouble finding online how to properly print out the error. Do I need to cast it? Before I added the exclamation mark, I was getting a warning that it's of type `Any`, which I don't believe I want here.

Comment: Since you are getting only a partial error, the `error` is an enumeration with the value `partialError`. You should log the error passed to the `perRecordCompletionBlock` to get the specific error for each record

Comment: Thanks; I didn't realize I needed both of those functions. I am still having issues with printing the error though. I edited my post above to include my `perRecordCompletionBlock` code. I tried to cast the error as `NSError` in hopes that that would make things print out...but still nothing...

Comment: oh, i'm going to try `.localizedDescription`

Comment: :( `print(error!.localizedDescription)` didn't work

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast the error.  Just `print(error)`

Comment: hm, when I don't cast, I get a warning that says `Expression implicitly coerced from 'Error?' to Any`. Also, no errors print out....unless there is no error, but that would be really weird since the code in the `error == nil` block of `modifyRecordsCompletionBlock` doesn't execute.

Comment: You can get rid of that warning by using print("\(error)").  You can also set a breakpoint in the per record completionHandler and examine error

Comment: I set the breakpoint at `operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { record, error in`. Oddly, the breakpoint was never reached...is there anything fancy I need to do to set this breakpoint since it's in a different thread from the main one? (Alternatively, maybe the control flow just isn't going where I think it should be. I'll explore that.)

Comment: No, the breakpoint should fire regardless of thread

Comment: You can see how I handle errors in the function `applyLocalChangesToServer` in https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3/blob/master/Sources/Classes/SMStoreSyncOperation.swift  In this case I am casting to `NSError` but if your breakpoint isn't firing then that indicates the completion closure isn't running anyway

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I finally figured it out! First, something was wrong with my button. I'm not sure what it was, but I deleted the old action and ctrl-dragged again and pasted my code in again. Then my errors started printing out! Found out it was a permissions problem--it was a quick fix: needed to give write permissions to those who aren't creators of the post. YAYYY Thanks again!